# How can Datum be decoded from utxos that were generated using MeshJs Marketplace Smart Contracts?

Tags: mesh, datum-hash, decode

I have datum that was formed using the MeshJS Marketplace Smart Contract.
Can someone help me with the process to decode the datum. I have tried various methods mentioned in their discord with no success. NOTE: I have saved the values needed to form the datum but I want to know the process in which I can decode the datum hashes from the utxos.

The full utxo that shows up from cardano-cli is :

```
2d66a297a1add05094885b29158561f6786b2f473010a77f8954b3caea620794     0        1336100 lovelace + 1 ec869b653472b4f68cc86e14731723bdd97573f0a7ccf81a0fc6b8c6.476f6c64656e20427574746572666c79 + TxOutDatumHash ScriptDataInBabbageEra "b600faebcefacd601d3a7a741ae60ebadcc450e745f53b8df3ea3b9f1cdfbf82"
```

The datum hash is:

```
b600faebcefacd601d3a7a741ae60ebadcc450e745f53b8df3ea3b9f1cdfbf82
```